# Улучшить распознавание цифр, конфиг, traindata

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
def tesseract(img):
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
        img = cv2.imread(img)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)#IMREAD_ANYCOLOR
        custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
        data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config).lower()
        return data
```

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь распознать цифры с запятой, но на маленьком разрешение не находит точку. Я не смог найти документацию где бы мне объяснили как настраивается конфиг. Есть ли возможность указать что я ищу только цифры и можно ли указать точность распознавания. Так-же в какойто англоязычной статье чтото было про traindata. К сожалению английским не владею. Вопросы:
Как настраивать конфиг? Можно ли указать что мне нужны только цифры с плавающей запятой? Есть ли какието тренировочные пакеты (не знаю как правильно назвать) и как их устанавливать?

Comment: "распознавание".

Comment: @strawdog, не могу не согласится. Спасибо.